# example of customer survey in the confirmation page

Tags: e-commerce, surveys, confirmation

i am looking for some examples of customer survey in confirmation/thank you page in ecommerce website, Where customers asked to fill a survey after the purchase compilation.

Example : Apple thank you page 
http://www.getelastic.com/11-ways-to-optimize-thank-you-pages/

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like Uber's confirmation and driver rating screen, embedding a very simple survey question (perhaps an NPS score, or something else that could be measured on a single scale):

[image: Uber Confirmation/Rating survey]

This could be easily modified to work in a full-width context.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that the more stars you give people to choose from, the less likely people are to respond.

A simple "rate" thumbs up, thumbs down will get the highest response rate.